Quota for tabledata.list limits
Few times a day our team members is getting this error:
Exceeded rate limits: Your project:392773166868 exceeded quota for tabledata.list bytes per second per project.
We checked metrics for tabledata.list usage, our peak usage is 35%, however we have 3 projects. Does this quote is equally divided across all projects?
enter image description here
